# I want to add x and 3 to the product name when we add 3 products to the card?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xslt

I want to add `x` and `3` to the product name when we add 3 products to the card? for ex: `Product Name x 3`.

```
if(checkGreatrThan(quantity)){
      tableRow +='<div  class="prod-title-col order-summary-col2 '+lastIndex+'"><h3 class="prod-title" >'+ value.product_name + '<span>'+ 'x '+value.quantity+'</span>+'</h3></div>' ;
 }
  else {
     tableRow +='<div  class="prod-title-col order-summary-col2 '+lastIndex+'"><h3 class="prod-title" >'+ value.product_name +'</h3></div>';
}
```

Can you format the statement?

Comment: Looks like a typo, maybe? ... change `'</span>+'</h3></div>'` => `'</span></h3></div>'`

Comment: No. it is not working... what my expecation is <h3>Product Name <span>x 3 </span></h3>

Comment: What is `value`? ... probably need to add a little more code/details to the question

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your variables are defined.

Your problem was, that you had in your first addition to tableRow some ' and + too much. So your javascript throwing that error.

```js
if(checkGreatrThan(quantity)){
  tableRow +='<div  class="prod-title-col order-summary-col2 '+lastIndex+'"><h3 class="prod-title" >'+ value.product_name + '<span>x '+value.quantity+'</span></h3></div>' ;
 }
  else {
 tableRow +='<div  class="prod-title-col order-summary-col2 '+lastIndex+'"><h3 class="prod-title" >'+ value.product_name +'</h3></div>';
}
```